# Colour code Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How is it possible to color my Nickname in Version 0.00.1?

I've tried the command `/nick &2b MyNickName` which causes in `Error command not found`.

Comment: `/Nick` is a command often from Essentials in Bukkit (a server for the main game) and as far as I'm aware it is not possible to color your name in the Pocket Edition.

Comment: It's not possible in vanilla game

Comment: Doesn't work without mods, the full list of (vanilla) text colouring options can be seen here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Formatting_codes

Answer (score 1):

No, this is sadly not possible within the vanilla game